# Asymmetric digital signature Node.JS

Tags: node.js, cryptography, digital-signature

I need to find some criptographic solution, which allows me to sign some data using private key, and check signature using public key. Would be great if there is some nodejs package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like your needs should be met by the built-in [crypto](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/all.html#crypto) package, no? Check the docs on the `createSign` and `createVerify` methods, and the `signer` and `verifier` objects they respectively generate. Note that these require your system to have `openssl` installed where Node can find it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes, crupto module is what I need. It seems that `crypto` haven't built-in way to generate public-private key for signing/veriying, and I should use `openssl` command, right?

Comment: Yes, there don't appear to be any cryptographic randomness functions built into Node.js. Though it looks like there's a nice wrapper library around `openssl` for this: https://github.com/akdubya/rbytes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sign xml there is [xml-crypto](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto) - an [xml digital signature library for node.js](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto)